# Determinant of a small complex matrix within a GPU thread

Tags: cuda, eigen, cublas, determinants

The problem is to compute the determinant of a complex matrix (5x5, 4x4, and 3x3) from a device function within a particular thread. Efficiency is crucial, as the original problem involves computing thousands of such matrices in a for loop within each thread.

Here is a working example using `direct expansion` (run with arg: 0) and `cofactor expansion` (run with arg: 1) methods:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

#define N 5

__host__ __device__ static __inline__  cuDoubleComplex cuCfms( cuDoubleComplex x, 
                                                               cuDoubleComplex y, 
                                                               cuDoubleComplex d){
    double real_res;
    double imag_res;
    
    real_res = (cuCreal(x) *  cuCreal(y)) - cuCreal(d);
    imag_res = (cuCreal(x) *  cuCimag(y)) - cuCimag(d);
            
    real_res = -(cuCimag(x) * cuCimag(y))  + real_res;  
    imag_res =  (cuCimag(x) *  cuCreal(y)) + imag_res;     
     
    return make_cuDoubleComplex(real_res, imag_res);
}

__host__ __device__ static __inline__ cuDoubleComplex cuCaaaa(cuDoubleComplex x,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex y,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex u,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex v) {

    return make_cuDoubleComplex (cuCreal(x) + cuCreal(y) + cuCreal(u) + cuCreal(v), 
                                 cuCimag(x) + cuCimag(y) + cuCimag(u) + cuCimag(v));
}

__host__ __device__ static __inline__ cuDoubleComplex cuCasas(cuDoubleComplex x,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex y,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex u,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex v) {

    return make_cuDoubleComplex (cuCreal(x) - cuCreal(y) + cuCreal(u) - cuCreal(v), 
                                 cuCimag(x) - cuCimag(y) + cuCimag(u) - cuCimag(v));
}

__host__ __device__ static __inline__ cuDoubleComplex cuCasasa(cuDoubleComplex x,
                                                               cuDoubleComplex y,
                                                               cuDoubleComplex u,
                                                               cuDoubleComplex v,
                                                               cuDoubleComplex w) {

    return make_cuDoubleComplex (cuCreal(x) - cuCreal(y) + cuCreal(u) - cuCreal(v) + cuCreal(w), 
                                 cuCimag(x) - cuCimag(y) + cuCimag(u) - cuCimag(v) + cuCimag(w) );
}


__device__ cuDoubleComplex cuC_5pos (cuDoubleComplex a, cuDoubleComplex b,
                                   cuDoubleComplex c, cuDoubleComplex d,
                                   cuDoubleComplex e) {
     // B[12]*(B[18]*B[24] - B[19]*B[23])
    //a*b*c -d*e
    return cuCmul(a, cuCfms(b,c, cuCmul(d,e)));
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex cuC_5neg (cuDoubleComplex a, cuDoubleComplex b,
                                   cuDoubleComplex c, cuDoubleComplex d,
                                   cuDoubleComplex e) {
     // B[12]*(B[18]*B[24] - B[19]*B[23])
    //a*b*c -d*e
    return cuCmul(cuCmul(make_cuDoubleComplex(-1.0,0.0),a), cuCfms(b,c, cuCmul(d,e)));
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex direct_det5 (cuDoubleComplex *B){
    cuDoubleComplex det;

    cuDoubleComplex det1 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det2 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det3 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det4 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det5 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);


    cuDoubleComplex det11 = cuCmul(B[0],cuCmul(B[6],cuCadd( cuC_5pos(B[12],B[18],B[24],B[19],B[23]), 
                                                   cuCadd(  cuC_5neg(B[13],B[17],B[24],B[22],B[19]), 
                                                            cuC_5pos(B[14],B[17],B[23],B[22],B[18]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det12 = cuCmul(B[0],cuCmul(B[11],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[7],B[18],B[24],B[19],B[23]), 
                                                    cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[8],B[17],B[24],B[22],B[19]), 
                                                            cuC_5pos(B[9],B[17],B[23],B[22],B[18]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det13 = cuCmul(B[0],cuCmul(B[16],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[7],B[13],B[24],B[23],B[14]), 
                                                    cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[8],B[12],B[24],B[22],B[14]), 
                                                            cuC_5pos(B[9],B[12],B[23],B[22],B[13]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det14 = cuCmul(B[0],cuCmul(B[21],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[7],B[13],B[19],B[18],B[14]), 
                                                    cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[8],B[12],B[19],B[17],B[14]), 
                                                            cuC_5pos(B[9],B[12],B[18],B[13],B[17]) ) ) ) );

    det1 = cuCasas(det11, det12, det13, det14);


    cuDoubleComplex det21 = cuCmul(B[1*5+0],cuCmul(B[0*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[12],B[18],B[24],B[19],B[23]), cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[13],B[17],B[24],B[22],B[19]), cuC_5pos(B[14],B[17],B[23],B[22],B[18]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det22 = cuCmul(B[1*5+0],cuCmul(B[2*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[2],B[18],B[24],B[19],B[23]), cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[3],B[17],B[24],B[22],B[19]), cuC_5pos(B[4],B[17],B[23],B[22],B[18]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det23 = cuCmul(B[1*5+0],cuCmul(B[3*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[2],B[13],B[24],B[23],B[14]), cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[3],B[12],B[24],B[22],B[14]), cuC_5pos(B[4],B[12],B[23],B[22],B[13]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det24 = cuCmul(B[1*5+0],cuCmul(B[4*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[2],B[13],B[19],B[18],B[14]), cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[3],B[12],B[19],B[17],B[14]), cuC_5pos(B[4],B[12],B[18],B[13],B[17]) ) ) ) );

    det2 = cuCasas(det21, det22, det23, det24);


    cuDoubleComplex det31 = cuCmul(B[10],cuCmul(B[0*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[1*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[3*5+4],B[4*5+3]), 
                                                       cuCadd(  cuC_5neg(B[1*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[3*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[1*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[3*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det32 = cuCmul(B[10],cuCmul(B[1*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[3*5+4],B[4*5+3]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[3*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[3*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det33 = cuCmul(B[10],cuCmul(B[3*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[1*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det34 = cuCmul(B[10],cuCmul(B[4*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[1*5+3],B[3*5+2]) ) ) ) );


    det3 = cuCasas(det31, det32, det33, det34);


    cuDoubleComplex det41 = cuCmul(B[15],cuCmul(B[0*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[1*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[2*5+4],B[4*5+3]), 
                                                       cuCadd(  cuC_5neg(B[1*5+3],B[2*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[2*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[1*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[2*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det42 = cuCmul(B[15],cuCmul(B[1*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[2*5+4],B[4*5+3]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[2*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[2*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[2*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det43 = cuCmul(B[15],cuCmul(B[2*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[1*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det44 = cuCmul(B[15],cuCmul(B[4*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[2*5+4],B[2*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[2*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[1*5+3],B[2*5+2]) ) ) ) );


    det4 = cuCasas(det41, det42, det43, det44);


    cuDoubleComplex det51 = cuCmul(B[20],cuCmul(B[0*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[1*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[3*5+4],B[2*5+4],B[3*5+3]), 
                                                       cuCadd(  cuC_5neg(B[1*5+3],B[2*5+2],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[2*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[1*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[2*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det52 = cuCmul(B[20],cuCmul(B[1*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[3*5+4],B[2*5+4],B[3*5+3]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[2*5+2],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[2*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[2*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det53 = cuCmul(B[20],cuCmul(B[2*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[1*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det54 = cuCmul(B[20],cuCmul(B[3*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[2*5+4],B[2*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[2*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[1*5+3],B[2*5+2]) ) ) ) );


    det5 = cuCasas(det51, det52, det53, det54);

    det = cuCasasa(det1,det2,det3,det4,det5);

    return det;
}


#define N 5

__device__ cuDoubleComplex det_4x4(cuDoubleComplex *matrix) {
    cuDoubleComplex det = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det1 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det2 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det3 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det4 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);

    // Calculate the determinant using cofactor expansions
    det1 = cuCmul(matrix[0], 
                  cuCadd( cuCsub( cuCmul( matrix[5], 
                                          cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[15]), 
                                                  cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[14]) ))
                                 ,cuCmul(matrix[6], 
                                         cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[15]),
                                                 cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[13]) ) ) )
                         ,cuCmul(matrix[7], 
                                 cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[14]),
                                         cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[13]) ) ) ) );



    det2 = cuCmul(matrix[1], 
                  cuCadd( cuCsub( cuCmul( matrix[4], 
                                          cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[15]), 
                                                  cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[14]) ))
                                 ,cuCmul(matrix[6], 
                                         cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[15]),
                                                 cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[12]) ) ) )
                         ,cuCmul(matrix[7], 
                                 cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[14]),
                                         cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[12]) ) ) ) );


    det3 = cuCmul(matrix[2], 
                  cuCadd( cuCsub( cuCmul( matrix[4], 
                                          cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[15]), 
                                                  cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[13]) ))
                                 ,cuCmul(matrix[5], 
                                         cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[15]),
                                                 cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[12]) ) ) )
                         ,cuCmul(matrix[7], 
                                 cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[13]),
                                         cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[12]) ) ) ) );
    
    
    det4 = cuCmul(matrix[3], 
                  cuCadd( cuCsub( cuCmul( matrix[4], 
                                          cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[14]), 
                                                  cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[13]) ))
                                 ,cuCmul(matrix[5], 
                                         cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[14]),
                                                 cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[12]) ) ) )
                         ,cuCmul(matrix[6], 
                                 cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[13]),
                                         cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[12]) ) ) ) );
    
    det = cuCsub( cuCadd(det1,det3), cuCadd(det2,det4) );

    return det;
}


__device__ cuDoubleComplex det_5x5(cuDoubleComplex *matrix) {
    cuDoubleComplex det = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);


    // Calculate the determinant using cofactor expansions
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
        cuDoubleComplex submatrix[N-1][N-1];
        int subrow = 0, subcol = 0;

        // Create the submatrix by excluding the current row and column
        for (int row = 1; row < N; row++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
                if (c == col) {
                    continue;
                }
                submatrix[subrow][subcol] = matrix[row * N + c];
                subcol++;
            }
            subrow++;
            subcol = 0;
        }

        // Calculate the cofactor
        cuDoubleComplex det_sign = make_cuDoubleComplex((col % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1),0.0);
        cuDoubleComplex cofactor = cuCmul( cuCmul(det_sign,matrix[col]), det_4x4(&submatrix[0][0]));


        // Accumulate the cofactors to calculate the determinant
        det = cuCadd(det, cofactor);
    }


    return det;
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex gpu_device_kernel(int i, int method) {


    // some random data, depending on `i`, but for simplification say constant data
    cuDoubleComplex matrix[5*5] = {
            make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 2.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(7.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(8.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(6.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 2.0)
    };

    cuDoubleComplex cf_sign[5]={make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0,0.0),
                                make_cuDoubleComplex(-1.0,0.0),
                                make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0,0.0),
                                make_cuDoubleComplex(-1.0,0.0),
                                make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0,0.0),
                                };

    cuDoubleComplex det;
    if (method == 0) {
        det = direct_det5(matrix);    
    } else {
        det = det_5x5(matrix);
    }

    return det;
}


__global__ void gpu_global_kernel(cuDoubleComplex *d_res, int method) {

    // some other computations, irrelevant to current problem

    uint64_t total = 69120 * 1000;// 10 * 1000 * 1000; // this `total` is what I am referring to thousands 
    
    cuDoubleComplex det_sum, det;
    det_sum = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        det = gpu_device_kernel(i, method);
        det_sum = cuCadd(det_sum, det);
    }

    det_sum = cuCmul(det_sum, make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0/total,0.0) );

    d_res[0] = det_sum;

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <num1> <num2>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int method;
    method = atoi(argv[1]);
    
    double complex *res;
    res = (double complex*)malloc(sizeof(double complex));
    memset(res, 0.0,sizeof(double complex));


    cuDoubleComplex *d_res;
    cudaMalloc(&d_res, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) );

    int *d_method;
    cudaMalloc(&d_method, sizeof(int) );
    cudaMemcpy(d_method, &method, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    clock_t direct_start, direct_end;
    direct_start = clock();

    gpu_global_kernel <<<1,1>>>(d_res, *d_method);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    direct_end = clock();

    cudaMemcpy(res, d_res, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    printf("RESULT: %.16E + %.16E i\n", creal(res[0]), cimag(res[0]));

    double direct_time = (double)((double)(direct_end - direct_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    if (method == 0) {
        printf("DIRECT EXEC: %.5f s \n", direct_time);
    } else {
        printf("COFACTOR EXEC: %.5f s \n", direct_time);        
    }    

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am wondering if these implementation is even efficient.

I am looking for an alternative method to compute the determinant of a general matrix inside a device function. The example I have provided is one of the most straightforward methods, but an alternative approach, such as LU/Cholesky decomposition, that can be called from the device function is what I am seeking. Unfortunately, packages like LAPACK are not available for CUDA, but maybe a similar compatible function from some other packages could work within the CUDA device environment.

Any suggestions or function examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the function performs uncoalesced memory accesses if multiple threads operate on multiple matrices

Comment: You could just take a serial c++ implementation for the desired operations and make them device functions to see if this improves the performance

Comment: If you are happy to use cofactor expansion, it should be perfectly possible to use computer algebra to explicitly expand the 4x4 and 5x5 cases into a giant stream of multiply-add operations without any of the code in your question. And within that code is a whole lot of waste. You are doing huge amounts of unnecessary copying, and things like calculating the cofactor signs at runtime is just silly. It is a fixed 5x5 case: precompute them

Comment: @talonmies I precompute the cofactors, it gave me 0.1s improvement for `5 * 1000 * 24 * 24 * 24` matrices. Can you point out the unnecessary copying that can be removed? Also, about "computer algebra to explicitly expand the `4x4` and `5x5` cases into a giant stream of multiply-add operations without any of the code in your question", can you please explain more? I have tried the direct expansion for `5x5` (similar to `4x4` above), but dealing with `cuDoubleComplex`datatypes the code becomes excessively convoluted and hard to comprehend

Comment: you do not need to make a copy of each submatrix, or any of the loops at all. you know beforehand which elements to multiply since its a closed-form expression. simply write it down like njuffa showed you in the nvidia forum. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-device-calculation-for-determinants-of-thousands-of-small-complex-matrices-on-each-thread/254531/2?u=striker159

Comment: @AbatorAbetor He did it for a `4x4` matrix and there was no improvement in efficiency. Also, are you suggest doing that for a `5x5` matrices with `cuDoubleComplex` data type? Do you understand how many such terms will be there?

Comment: It's 120 terms, each of which is formed from the complex product of 5 entries in the 5x5 matrix. Which is why you use a computer algebra system to *write the code for you* so that you don't have to do it all by hand. Once the code is written, you don't have to care what it looks like, only that it works, is correct and sufficiently stable for your use case, and is fast

Comment: @talonmies I have added the direct expansion C code. So you mean this is the most efficient method to compute a general `5x5` matrix determinant? There are no functions in CUDA to compute general `5x5` matrix determinant faster?

Comment: Did you test the direct code? Is it correct? Is it faster?

Comment: The direct approach in the code is slightly faster compared to cofactor expansion. After observing that direct expansion is not commonly available in CUDA implementations, I included it in the question. Are there any other methods that can potentially offer even better performance? I experimented with LU decomposition, but it was relatively slower in my tests.

Comment: Can you show your full benchmark code that times and  compares both approaches with a fully utilized gpu? What GPU are you using? What is the compilation command? Then we have a proper baseline

Comment: Look, it is quite straightforward: GPUs are basically high performance parallel floating point multiply-add machines. Any code you can reduce to a stream of floating point multiply-add instructions will be intrinsically faster than code with branches, jumps, call stack setup/teardown, etc **IF** the data for the stream of floating point instructions can be accessed in a fashion which suits the memory controller structure in the GPU. You have not shown us anything about the latter in any of your questions about this so far. Answering this is very difficult without seeing your real use case

Comment: for 69'120'000 matrices using an A100, I see around factor 8.2 speedup with the direct expansion, and additional 10% speedup with coalesced memory accesses. If you can confirm that with your benchmark code, and in the real application its only slightly faster with the direct expansion, determinat calculation is clearly not the bottleneck of the real code.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor 8.2x speedup compared to cofactor expansion? What are your timestamps? Also can you please share your code, I am confused about memory coalesced implementation.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor I am using `Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB`. `Direct expansion` takes `18.97s` and `cofactor` takes `40.77s` for `69 120 000` matrices

Comment: @AbatorAbetor I have also updated the code with both these methods

Comment: That is a completely different kernel than in your original posting. The original kernel loaded the matrix from memory, and the compiler put the submatrix in local memory which made the kernel horribly slow.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor I really appreciate your help. Can we connect via Zoom/Skype?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are including a C++ header `(<cstring>)` I am assuming its a C++ code, even though it looks very C-like.

I took the general generated code that you provided for expansion and implemented it directly as is by simply defining the operators `*,+,-` for the `cuDoubleComplex` .

I call this method "generated" in the code below. Additionally, I made some slight modifications to your code. I added a program parameter to specify the number of GPU threads to have a proper GPU utilization. I also use separate kernels for each method. Method 0 is the original method, method 1 is your direct method, method 2 is my "generated" method.

I compiled the code with `nvcc -std=c++14 -O3 -arch=sm_70 main.cu -o main` and see the following timings on V100 Pcie for 32000 GPU threads.

| Configuration | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| original | 145.01487 s |
| direct | 67.07063 s |
| generated | 24.02771 s |

The code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

#define N 5


__host__ __device__
bool operator==(cuDoubleComplex l, cuDoubleComplex r){
    return cuCreal(l) == cuCreal(r) && cuCimag(l) == cuCimag(r);
}

__host__ __device__
cuDoubleComplex operator*(cuDoubleComplex l, cuDoubleComplex r){
    return cuCmul(l,r);
}

__host__ __device__
cuDoubleComplex operator+(cuDoubleComplex l, cuDoubleComplex r){
    return cuCadd(l,r);
}

__host__ __device__
cuDoubleComplex operator-(cuDoubleComplex l, cuDoubleComplex r){
    return cuCsub(l,r);
}

__host__ __device__
cuDoubleComplex operator-(cuDoubleComplex l){
    return make_cuDoubleComplex(-cuCreal(l), -cuCimag(l));
}


template<class Matrix>
__device__ 
cuDoubleComplex generated_det_5x5(Matrix B){
    return 
       B[0*5+0]*(B[1*5+1]*(B[2*5+2]*(B[3*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[3*5+4]*B[4*5+3])-B[2*5+3]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+4])+B[2*5+4]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+3]))-B[2*5+1]*(B[1*5+2]*(B[3*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[3*5+4]*B[4*5+3])-B[1*5+3]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+4])+B[1*5+4]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+3]))+B[3*5+1]*(B[1*5+2]*(B[2*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+3]*B[2*5+4])-B[1*5+3]*(B[2*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[2*5+4])+B[1*5+4]*(B[2*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[2*5+3]))-B[4*5+1]*(B[1*5+2]*(B[2*5+3]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+3]*B[2*5+4])-B[1*5+3]*(B[2*5+2]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+2]*B[2*5+4])+B[1*5+4]*(B[2*5+2]*B[3*5+3]-B[2*5+3]*B[3*5+2])))
     - B[1*5+0]*(B[0*5+1]*(B[2*5+2]*(B[3*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[3*5+4]*B[4*5+3])-B[2*5+3]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+4])+B[2*5+4]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+3]))-B[2*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[3*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[3*5+4]*B[4*5+3])-B[0*5+3]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+3]))+B[3*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[2*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+3]*B[2*5+4])-B[0*5+3]*(B[2*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[2*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[2*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[2*5+3]))-B[4*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[2*5+3]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+3]*B[2*5+4])-B[0*5+3]*(B[2*5+2]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+2]*B[2*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[2*5+2]*B[3*5+3]-B[2*5+3]*B[3*5+2])))
     + B[2*5+0]*(B[0*5+1]*(B[1*5+2]*(B[3*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[3*5+4]*B[4*5+3])-B[1*5+3]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+4])+B[1*5+4]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+3]))-B[1*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[3*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[3*5+4]*B[4*5+3])-B[0*5+3]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[3*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[3*5+3]))+B[3*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[1*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+3]*B[1*5+4])-B[0*5+3]*(B[1*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[1*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[1*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[1*5+3]))-B[4*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[1*5+3]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+3]*B[1*5+4])-B[0*5+3]*(B[1*5+2]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+2]*B[1*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[1*5+2]*B[3*5+3]-B[1*5+3]*B[3*5+2])))
     - B[3*5+0]*(B[0*5+1]*(B[1*5+2]*(B[2*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[2*5+4]*B[4*5+3])-B[1*5+3]*(B[2*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[2*5+4])+B[1*5+4]*(B[2*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[2*5+3]))-B[1*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[2*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[2*5+4]*B[4*5+3])-B[0*5+3]*(B[2*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[2*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[2*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[2*5+3]))+B[2*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[1*5+3]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+3]*B[1*5+4])-B[0*5+3]*(B[1*5+2]*B[4*5+4]-B[4*5+2]*B[1*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[1*5+2]*B[4*5+3]-B[4*5+2]*B[1*5+3]))-B[4*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[1*5+3]*B[2*5+4]-B[2*5+3]*B[1*5+4])-B[0*5+3]*(B[1*5+2]*B[2*5+4]-B[2*5+2]*B[1*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[1*5+2]*B[2*5+3]-B[1*5+3]*B[2*5+2])))
     + B[4*5+0]*(B[0*5+1]*(B[1*5+2]*(B[2*5+3]*B[3*5+4]-B[2*5+4]*B[3*5+3])-B[1*5+3]*(B[2*5+2]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+2]*B[2*5+4])+B[1*5+4]*(B[2*5+2]*B[3*5+3]-B[3*5+2]*B[2*5+3]))-B[1*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[2*5+3]*B[3*5+4]-B[2*5+4]*B[3*5+3])-B[0*5+3]*(B[2*5+2]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+2]*B[2*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[2*5+2]*B[3*5+3]-B[3*5+2]*B[2*5+3]))+B[2*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[1*5+3]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+3]*B[1*5+4])-B[0*5+3]*(B[1*5+2]*B[3*5+4]-B[3*5+2]*B[1*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[1*5+2]*B[3*5+3]-B[3*5+2]*B[1*5+3]))-B[3*5+1]*(B[0*5+2]*(B[1*5+3]*B[2*5+4]-B[2*5+3]*B[1*5+4])-B[0*5+3]*(B[1*5+2]*B[2*5+4]-B[2*5+2]*B[1*5+4])+B[0*5+4]*(B[1*5+2]*B[2*5+3]-B[1*5+3]*B[2*5+2])));
}








__host__ __device__ static __inline__  cuDoubleComplex cuCfms( cuDoubleComplex x, 
                                                               cuDoubleComplex y, 
                                                               cuDoubleComplex d){
    double real_res;
    double imag_res;
    
    real_res = (cuCreal(x) *  cuCreal(y)) - cuCreal(d);
    imag_res = (cuCreal(x) *  cuCimag(y)) - cuCimag(d);
            
    real_res = -(cuCimag(x) * cuCimag(y))  + real_res;  
    imag_res =  (cuCimag(x) *  cuCreal(y)) + imag_res;     
     
    return make_cuDoubleComplex(real_res, imag_res);
}

__host__ __device__ static __inline__ cuDoubleComplex cuCaaaa(cuDoubleComplex x,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex y,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex u,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex v) {

    return make_cuDoubleComplex (cuCreal(x) + cuCreal(y) + cuCreal(u) + cuCreal(v), 
                                 cuCimag(x) + cuCimag(y) + cuCimag(u) + cuCimag(v));
}

__host__ __device__ static __inline__ cuDoubleComplex cuCasas(cuDoubleComplex x,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex y,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex u,
                                                              cuDoubleComplex v) {

    return make_cuDoubleComplex (cuCreal(x) - cuCreal(y) + cuCreal(u) - cuCreal(v), 
                                 cuCimag(x) - cuCimag(y) + cuCimag(u) - cuCimag(v));
}

__host__ __device__ static __inline__ cuDoubleComplex cuCasasa(cuDoubleComplex x,
                                                               cuDoubleComplex y,
                                                               cuDoubleComplex u,
                                                               cuDoubleComplex v,
                                                               cuDoubleComplex w) {

    return make_cuDoubleComplex (cuCreal(x) - cuCreal(y) + cuCreal(u) - cuCreal(v) + cuCreal(w), 
                                 cuCimag(x) - cuCimag(y) + cuCimag(u) - cuCimag(v) + cuCimag(w) );
}


__device__ cuDoubleComplex cuC_5pos (cuDoubleComplex a, cuDoubleComplex b,
                                   cuDoubleComplex c, cuDoubleComplex d,
                                   cuDoubleComplex e) {
     // B[12]*(B[18]*B[24] - B[19]*B[23])
    //a*b*c -d*e
    return cuCmul(a, cuCfms(b,c, cuCmul(d,e)));
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex cuC_5neg (cuDoubleComplex a, cuDoubleComplex b,
                                   cuDoubleComplex c, cuDoubleComplex d,
                                   cuDoubleComplex e) {
     // B[12]*(B[18]*B[24] - B[19]*B[23])
    //a*b*c -d*e
    return cuCmul(cuCmul(make_cuDoubleComplex(-1.0,0.0),a), cuCfms(b,c, cuCmul(d,e)));
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex direct_det5 (cuDoubleComplex *B){
    cuDoubleComplex det;

    cuDoubleComplex det1 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det2 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det3 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det4 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det5 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);


    cuDoubleComplex det11 = cuCmul(B[0],cuCmul(B[6],cuCadd( cuC_5pos(B[12],B[18],B[24],B[19],B[23]), 
                                                   cuCadd(  cuC_5neg(B[13],B[17],B[24],B[22],B[19]), 
                                                            cuC_5pos(B[14],B[17],B[23],B[22],B[18]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det12 = cuCmul(B[0],cuCmul(B[11],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[7],B[18],B[24],B[19],B[23]), 
                                                    cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[8],B[17],B[24],B[22],B[19]), 
                                                            cuC_5pos(B[9],B[17],B[23],B[22],B[18]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det13 = cuCmul(B[0],cuCmul(B[16],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[7],B[13],B[24],B[23],B[14]), 
                                                    cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[8],B[12],B[24],B[22],B[14]), 
                                                            cuC_5pos(B[9],B[12],B[23],B[22],B[13]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det14 = cuCmul(B[0],cuCmul(B[21],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[7],B[13],B[19],B[18],B[14]), 
                                                    cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[8],B[12],B[19],B[17],B[14]), 
                                                            cuC_5pos(B[9],B[12],B[18],B[13],B[17]) ) ) ) );

    det1 = cuCasas(det11, det12, det13, det14);


    cuDoubleComplex det21 = cuCmul(B[1*5+0],cuCmul(B[0*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[12],B[18],B[24],B[19],B[23]), cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[13],B[17],B[24],B[22],B[19]), cuC_5pos(B[14],B[17],B[23],B[22],B[18]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det22 = cuCmul(B[1*5+0],cuCmul(B[2*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[2],B[18],B[24],B[19],B[23]), cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[3],B[17],B[24],B[22],B[19]), cuC_5pos(B[4],B[17],B[23],B[22],B[18]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det23 = cuCmul(B[1*5+0],cuCmul(B[3*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[2],B[13],B[24],B[23],B[14]), cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[3],B[12],B[24],B[22],B[14]), cuC_5pos(B[4],B[12],B[23],B[22],B[13]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det24 = cuCmul(B[1*5+0],cuCmul(B[4*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[2],B[13],B[19],B[18],B[14]), cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[3],B[12],B[19],B[17],B[14]), cuC_5pos(B[4],B[12],B[18],B[13],B[17]) ) ) ) );

    det2 = cuCasas(det21, det22, det23, det24);


    cuDoubleComplex det31 = cuCmul(B[10],cuCmul(B[0*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[1*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[3*5+4],B[4*5+3]), 
                                                       cuCadd(  cuC_5neg(B[1*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[3*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[1*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[3*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det32 = cuCmul(B[10],cuCmul(B[1*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[3*5+4],B[4*5+3]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[3*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[3*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det33 = cuCmul(B[10],cuCmul(B[3*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[1*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det34 = cuCmul(B[10],cuCmul(B[4*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[1*5+3],B[3*5+2]) ) ) ) );


    det3 = cuCasas(det31, det32, det33, det34);


    cuDoubleComplex det41 = cuCmul(B[15],cuCmul(B[0*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[1*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[2*5+4],B[4*5+3]), 
                                                       cuCadd(  cuC_5neg(B[1*5+3],B[2*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[2*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[1*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[2*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det42 = cuCmul(B[15],cuCmul(B[1*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[2*5+4],B[4*5+3]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[2*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[2*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[2*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det43 = cuCmul(B[15],cuCmul(B[2*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[4*5+4],B[4*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[4*5+3],B[4*5+2],B[1*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det44 = cuCmul(B[15],cuCmul(B[4*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[2*5+4],B[2*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[2*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[1*5+3],B[2*5+2]) ) ) ) );


    det4 = cuCasas(det41, det42, det43, det44);


    cuDoubleComplex det51 = cuCmul(B[20],cuCmul(B[0*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[1*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[3*5+4],B[2*5+4],B[3*5+3]), 
                                                       cuCadd(  cuC_5neg(B[1*5+3],B[2*5+2],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[2*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[1*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[2*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det52 = cuCmul(B[20],cuCmul(B[1*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[3*5+4],B[2*5+4],B[3*5+3]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[2*5+2],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[2*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[2*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det53 = cuCmul(B[20],cuCmul(B[2*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[3*5+4],B[3*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[3*5+3],B[3*5+2],B[1*5+3]) ) ) ) );
    cuDoubleComplex det54 = cuCmul(B[20],cuCmul(B[3*5+1],cuCadd(cuC_5pos(B[0*5+2],B[1*5+3],B[2*5+4],B[2*5+3],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                        cuCadd( cuC_5neg(B[0*5+3],B[1*5+2],B[2*5+4],B[2*5+2],B[1*5+4]), 
                                                                cuC_5pos(B[0*5+4],B[1*5+2],B[2*5+3],B[1*5+3],B[2*5+2]) ) ) ) );


    det5 = cuCasas(det51, det52, det53, det54);

    det = cuCasasa(det1,det2,det3,det4,det5);

    return det;
}



__device__ cuDoubleComplex det_4x4(cuDoubleComplex *matrix) {
    cuDoubleComplex det = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det1 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det2 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det3 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
    cuDoubleComplex det4 = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);

    // Calculate the determinant using cofactor expansions
    det1 = cuCmul(matrix[0], 
                  cuCadd( cuCsub( cuCmul( matrix[5], 
                                          cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[15]), 
                                                  cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[14]) ))
                                 ,cuCmul(matrix[6], 
                                         cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[15]),
                                                 cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[13]) ) ) )
                         ,cuCmul(matrix[7], 
                                 cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[14]),
                                         cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[13]) ) ) ) );



    det2 = cuCmul(matrix[1], 
                  cuCadd( cuCsub( cuCmul( matrix[4], 
                                          cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[15]), 
                                                  cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[14]) ))
                                 ,cuCmul(matrix[6], 
                                         cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[15]),
                                                 cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[12]) ) ) )
                         ,cuCmul(matrix[7], 
                                 cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[14]),
                                         cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[12]) ) ) ) );


    det3 = cuCmul(matrix[2], 
                  cuCadd( cuCsub( cuCmul( matrix[4], 
                                          cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[15]), 
                                                  cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[13]) ))
                                 ,cuCmul(matrix[5], 
                                         cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[15]),
                                                 cuCmul(matrix[11],matrix[12]) ) ) )
                         ,cuCmul(matrix[7], 
                                 cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[13]),
                                         cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[12]) ) ) ) );
    
    
    det4 = cuCmul(matrix[3], 
                  cuCadd( cuCsub( cuCmul( matrix[4], 
                                          cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[14]), 
                                                  cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[13]) ))
                                 ,cuCmul(matrix[5], 
                                         cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[14]),
                                                 cuCmul(matrix[10],matrix[12]) ) ) )
                         ,cuCmul(matrix[6], 
                                 cuCsub( cuCmul(matrix[8],matrix[13]),
                                         cuCmul(matrix[9],matrix[12]) ) ) ) );
    
    det = cuCsub( cuCadd(det1,det3), cuCadd(det2,det4) );

    return det;
}


__device__ cuDoubleComplex det_5x5(cuDoubleComplex *matrix) {
    cuDoubleComplex det = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);


    // Calculate the determinant using cofactor expansions
    #pragma unroll
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
        cuDoubleComplex submatrix[N-1][N-1];
        int subrow = 0, subcol = 0;

        // Create the submatrix by excluding the current row and column
        #pragma unroll
        for (int row = 1; row < N; row++) {
            #pragma unroll
            for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
                if (c == col) {
                    continue;
                }
                submatrix[subrow][subcol] = matrix[row * N + c];
                subcol++;
            }
            subrow++;
            subcol = 0;
        }

        // Calculate the cofactor
        cuDoubleComplex det_sign = make_cuDoubleComplex((col % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1),0.0);
        cuDoubleComplex cofactor = cuCmul( cuCmul(det_sign,matrix[col]), det_4x4(&submatrix[0][0]));


        // Accumulate the cofactors to calculate the determinant
        det = cuCadd(det, cofactor);
    }


    return det;
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex gpu_device_kernel_original(int i) {


    // some random data, depending on `i`, but for simplification say constant data
    cuDoubleComplex matrix[5*5] = {
            make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 2.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(7.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(8.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(6.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 2.0)
    };

    cuDoubleComplex det = det_5x5(matrix);

    return det;
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex gpu_device_kernel_direct(int i) {


    // some random data, depending on `i`, but for simplification say constant data
    cuDoubleComplex matrix[5*5] = {
            make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 2.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(7.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(8.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(6.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 2.0)
    };

    cuDoubleComplex det = direct_det5(matrix);    

    return det;
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex gpu_device_kernel_generated(int i) {


    // some random data, depending on `i`, but for simplification say constant data
    cuDoubleComplex matrix[5*5] = {
            make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 2.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(7.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(8.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 0.0),
            make_cuDoubleComplex(5.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(6.0*(i/69120 * 1000), 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(4.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(3.0, 0.0), make_cuDoubleComplex(2.0, 2.0)
    };

    cuDoubleComplex det = generated_det_5x5(matrix);    

    return det;
}


__global__ void gpu_global_kernel_original(cuDoubleComplex *d_res, int numGpuThreads) {
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(tid < numGpuThreads){

        // some other computations, irrelevant to current problem

        uint64_t total = 69120 * 1000;// 10 * 1000 * 1000; // this `total` is what I am referring to thousands 
        
        cuDoubleComplex det_sum, det;
        det_sum = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            det = gpu_device_kernel_original(i);
            det_sum = cuCadd(det_sum, det);
        }

        det_sum = cuCmul(det_sum, make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0/total,0.0) );

        d_res[tid] = det_sum;
    }
}


__global__ void gpu_global_kernel_direct(cuDoubleComplex *d_res, int numGpuThreads) {
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(tid < numGpuThreads){

        // some other computations, irrelevant to current problem

        uint64_t total = 69120 * 1000;// 10 * 1000 * 1000; // this `total` is what I am referring to thousands 
        
        cuDoubleComplex det_sum, det;
        det_sum = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            det = gpu_device_kernel_direct(i);
            det_sum = cuCadd(det_sum, det);
        }

        det_sum = cuCmul(det_sum, make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0/total,0.0) );

        d_res[tid] = det_sum;
    }
}


__global__ void gpu_global_kernel_generated(cuDoubleComplex *d_res, int numGpuThreads) {
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(tid < numGpuThreads){

        // some other computations, irrelevant to current problem

        uint64_t total = 69120 * 1000;// 10 * 1000 * 1000; // this `total` is what I am referring to thousands 
        
        cuDoubleComplex det_sum, det;
        det_sum = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0,0.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            det = gpu_device_kernel_generated(i);
            det_sum = cuCadd(det_sum, det);
        }

        det_sum = cuCmul(det_sum, make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0/total,0.0) );

        d_res[tid] = det_sum;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <method> [<numGpuThreads>]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("method: 0 = original, 1 = direct, 2 = generated(no explicit cucomplex)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int method;
    method = atoi(argv[1]);

    int numGpuThreads = 1;
    if(argc > 2){
        numGpuThreads = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    
    cuDoubleComplex *res;
    res = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc(sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * numGpuThreads);
    memset(res, 0.0,sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * numGpuThreads);


    cuDoubleComplex *d_res;
    cudaMalloc(&d_res, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * numGpuThreads );

    clock_t direct_start, direct_end;
    direct_start = clock();
    dim3 block = 128;
    dim3 grid = (numGpuThreads + block.x -1) / block.x;
    switch(method){
        case 0: printf("original\n"); gpu_global_kernel_original<<<grid,block>>>(d_res, numGpuThreads); break;
        case 1: printf("direct\n"); gpu_global_kernel_direct<<<grid,block>>>(d_res, numGpuThreads); break;
        case 2: printf("generated\n"); gpu_global_kernel_generated<<<grid,block>>>(d_res, numGpuThreads); break;
    }

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    direct_end = clock();

    //just copy the first result, not all numGpuThreads results
    cudaMemcpy(res, d_res, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    printf("RESULT: %.16E + %.16E i\n", cuCreal(res[0]), cuCimag(res[0]));

    double timing = (double)((double)(direct_end - direct_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    printf("time %.5f s\n", timing);

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you have implemented operator overloading, which is indeed beneficial. Could you please provide more information about memory coalescing? Additionally, can you further explain your statement "The original kernel loaded the matrix from memory, and the compiler put the submatrix in local memory which made the kernel horribly slow"

Comment: I tried implementing it to my original code and there the `generated` and `direct` versions are slower than the `original` version. Any idea why that can happen?

Comment: in your deleted code, the kernel used a stack frame of 256 bytes to store the submatrix in local memory. coalesced accesses are explained in the best practices guide. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory . I do not know why it is slower in your real code.

Comment: Can we connect via email or have a brief discussion via Zoom?